# Change "add to cart" button to "BUY NOW"

Tags: magento-1.7, addtocart

I have tried to edit the title "add to cart" button to "BUY NOW". but i dont what to do? please help me any one knows. 
app/design/frontend/default/Thems/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
but it doesn't works.

please help me to change this.

Comment: Do you have custom theme installed? Also this will change only in product page//

Comment: yes i add alreday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable template hint and check your code is called from which template file.if it is getting called from the base folder copy that template to the your theme directory and change their the title

to enable template hint you can refer http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/